# My code did not pass the efficiency test(JS). Can I get any ideas about what made my code inefficient?

Tags: javascript, performance

I was solving the algorithm question and realized that the code passed all the test cases, excluding the efficiency of the code. Initially, I used 2 'for loops' but soon found that the time complexity of 2 'for loops' would consume too much time, which makes the efficiency of the code bad. Thus, changed the code like this.

Q) All runners passed the marathon excluding only one marathoner. Write the code that returns a certain runner who did not complete the marathon. Here are the expected outputs.

[image: expected outputs]

```
function solution(participant, completion) {
  var sorted_index;
  
  for (let i=0; i<completion.length; i++){
    sorted_index = participant.indexOf(completion[i]);
  
    answer = participant.splice(sorted_index, 1);
  }

  return participant.toString();

}
```

Can I get any ideas about what makes the code inefficient and get any alternatives? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (let i in completion){
    sorted_index = participant.indexOf(completion[i]);
    answer = participant.splice(sorted_index, 1);
}
```

Comment: I can see the 'TypeError: participant.indexOf(...).splice is not a function' in the terminal. Think the indexOf returns the index, not an array so splice can't be applied there..?

Answer (score -1):

An alternative solution is utilizing `Array.prototype` methods, which are equipped so solve this kind of problem easily.

You can use `Array.prototype.find` which finds only the first occurence. It also handles duplicates like in the last case by removing any checked names.

```js
function solution(participant, completion) {
    return participant.find((person) => {
        if (completion.includes(person)) {
            completion.splice(completion.indexOf(person), 1);
        } else return true;
    });
}



console.log(solution(['kiki', 'leo', 'eden'], ['eden', 'kiki']));
console.log(solution(['marina', 'josipa', 'nikola', 'vinko', 'filipa'], ['marina', 'josipa', 'nikola', 'filipa']));
console.log(solution(['stanko', 'mislav', 'mislav', 'ana'], ['stanko', 'ana', 'mislav']));
```

Comment: This doesn't provide the output the OP wants.

Comment: me either..TT it returns an empty array

Comment: @JeongYeongmin You're right. I updated the answer with a version that works with your test cases and description.

Comment: yeah but still there's a problem in efficiency test(takes too much time to run the code)